# Is it fraud? Would banks ask for fees through bitcoin?

Tags: fraud, banks, qrcode

[image: certification]

So a man came to me on Instagram saying that he wanted to buy old money specifically from Hong Kong for a museum in Philadelphia, and that he would pay me good money for my old coins and bills, then he said he transferred the money through Bank of America but the money would only transfer into my Hong Kong bank account if I pay a verification fee to his bank through bitcoin atm with a QR code he gave me, he said the QR code belonged to the bank but I couldn’t check, it was very fishy so I started agitating him to test him and he sent this CERTIFICATION that he claims is from Bank of America. He also kept rushing the process And his English was strange and he never really answered my questions directly, he called the fees clearance fees, activation fees and verification fee on different occasions and now I’m so confused. I don’t use Bitcoin so I have no idea is this fraud or not. Please help!

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely a scam.

Even if an activation fee was a legitimate thing, they would just charge that amount out of the amount you were going to receive - if you were to receive $1000 and the fee was $5, they'd just give you $995. Beyond that, no bank I'm aware of charges fees in cryptocurrencies.

Don't send any money to these people.

Comment: There are also numerous errors in this "certification" that make it very obvious that it's a low quality fake created by someone who doesn't speak English well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes definitely a scam. Don't proceed further.